# Reading in a phrase & filtering out characters to find numbers C

Tags: c, arrays, printf, character

I'm trying to write a program that reads in a test phrase, ignores the characters, and stores the numbers in an array. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define max_length 60
void main ()
{
    int c;
    int input_chars[max_length];
    int length;
    int reverse = 0;
    int temp;
    printf ("Input the test phrase: ");
    length = 0;
    /* limit the length of the phrase to the first 60 chars */
    /* do not store any non-digit input */
    while ((c = getchar ()) != '\n' && length < max_length) {
        if (isdigit (c)) {
            input_chars[length] = c - 48;
            length++;
        }
    }
    for (length = 0; length < 60; length++) {
        printf ("The array is %d", input_chars[length]);
    }
    getch ();
}
```

It returns a value that isn't even close to the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: Using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I suggest `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
printf("The array is %d\n", input_chars[i]);
}`

Comment: Need to improve code for if condition and for loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Is there a way to print the array in one statement? I made the changes as you suggested (thanks, btw), and it prints in three different statements. I don't think that will harm my final code, but I'm just curious.

Comment: `for(temp=0;temp<length;printf("%d",input_chars[temp++]));` This is one statement named "for statement" ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.8.5.3)

Comment: Sorry, actually this is two statements: for statement and null statement ([N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.8.3).

Comment: I think that it is not possible  to print an array in  directly one statement. (indirect : call your custom function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using value of uninitialized variable `input_chars` having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

You should print only what you read in this case.

Other notes:

- You should format your code properly with indents.
- You should use `'0'` instead of the magic number `48`. (It is granteed that character codes for digits are consecutive, according to [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.1 Character Sets)
- You should use standard `int main(void)` instead of implementation-defined `void main()` unless you need to use latter.
- You should check if `c` is not `EOF` for safety.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define max_length 60
int main (void)
{
    int c;
    int input_chars[max_length];
    int length;
    int reverse=0;
    int temp;
    printf ("Input the test phrase: ");
    length = 0;
    /* limit the length of the phrase to the first 60 chars */
    /* do not store any non-digit input */
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && length < max_length) {
        if (isdigit(c)) 
        {
            input_chars[length] = c - '0'; length++;
        }
    }
    for(temp=0;temp<length;temp++){
        printf("The array is %d", input_chars[temp]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to format it correctly before posting, thanks! Regarding the '0', I was told that the function getchar() reads one character at a time and returns an integer to the left-hand-side variable c, which represents the ASCII value of that character.( For example, if the input character is a 7, its ASCII value is 55) and that to store in
the input_chars array an integer value of 7, c needs to be offset by
48 (55 – 48 = 7).